# Best way to store a large amount of static information in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

If I have a large amount of information that will be randomly used while the app is being used, what is the best way to store and access that data?

The app completely relies on the static text that I have and will need to grab certain parts and concatenate them depending on what the user selects within the app.

Is it best to load it into Core Data when the app loads the first time and then check if it is loaded every time after that? If so, how?

Comment: Is the large amount of information from the internet? Or from a file/resource in the app?

Comment: No really enough information to go on here.

Comment: Let me give an example: In the english language we have prefixes and suffixes for words. Lets say i have a list of thousands of prefixes, and another of suffixes, And another of words that work with only select prefixes and suffixes. The relationship is a word has 0..* prefix and/or a suffix. if I want to take a list of prefixes and append them to a designated word. What is the best way to store these. I can see how to store these in core data but that makes a model object for each word, prefix, and suffix, which seems like alot of overhead for a small app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data is completely inappropriate for your use case.

Store your text in a `.strings` file and use `NSLocalizedString()` to access it. This will provide a convenient way to lookup text by key and make localization simple.

Comment: Let me give an example: In the english language we have prefixes and suffixes for words. Lets say i have a list of thousands of prefixes, and another of suffixes, And another of words that work with only select prefixes and suffixes. The relationship is a word has 0..* prefix and/or a suffix. if I want to take a list of prefixes and append them to a designated word. What is the best way to store these. I can see how to store these in core data but that makes a model object for each word, prefix, and suffix, which seems like alot of overhead for a small app.

Answer (score 1):

Core Data's primary focus is not persisting data but instead on managing a complex graph of objects that contain and manipulate data. The API is intended to create the entire model layer of a Model-View-Design application.

If you have a lot of chunks of text all that need separate logic or if your app will create those chunks out of a large body of text, then core data is a good choice.

If you just have something like a very basic text editor then probably not.

Comment: Let me give an example: In the english language we have prefixes and suffixes for words. Lets say i have a list of thousands of prefixes, and another of suffixes, And another of words that work with only select prefixes and suffixes. The relationship is a word has 0..* prefix and/or a suffix. if I want to take a list of prefixes and append them to a designated word. What is the best way to store these. I can see how to store these in core data but that makes a model object for each word, prefix, and suffix, which seems like alot of overhead for a small app.

Comment: You would need a different object for each word, prefix and suffix because in the real-world each word, prefix and suffix is a different thing and your data model should reflect the real-world objects. No matter what method/API you choose, you will end up having to model each word,prefix and suffix if you app needs to distinguish them. You might as well use Core Data and get all the benefits.

Comment: A three entity data model is not very complex.